# RF amp rating of ceramic capacitors

Tags: capacitor

Some one posed a question about current ratings in a capacitor and the replies basically came across as a non-issue except for what might be induced due to  ripple in various power supplies.  But what about one in RF service, where voltages may be low, but RF current passing though them can be 5 amps and up?  A typical circuit may have a 470 pF, 2 kV DC ceramic in line with a low Z load and have only a couple hundred volts across it, but passing several hundred watts of RF from VLF on up.

Where is that breaking point on the basic round, radial lead ceramic?

Comment: can you link to that question?

Comment: by the way, capitalization in units matter: 470 PF, 2 KVDC is "fourhundredandseventy pascal-farad, two kelvin-volt-debye-coloumb", which happens to be identical to "2 (As)²/(m³), 6.67·10⁻²⁷ g K m³/ (s²)", so one indication of square charge per volume, and one of energytemperaturedistance product, as useful when measuring the accelerating development of entropy over a length (i.e. practically never)

Comment: @MarcusMüller PF could also be petafarads, which sounds like an utterly terrifying unit.

Comment: Haven't tried to take a look at the datasheets?

Answer (score 0):

It's just in the datasheet, ESR and temperature vs ripple current. Even super generic capacitors have detailed datasheets. Purpose-built RF capacitors should have even more relevant information in their datasheets.

[image]

From Murata SimSurfer